# Internet download manager alternative for OS X?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, data-transfer

I was a longtime windows/linux user and just purchased a Mac, everything is great except that I need a good download manager for Mac which works like Internet Download Manager for Windows, I know some things would be different but I am specifically looking for following feature

- ability to resume downloads
- automatic capture of downloads from browsers such as firefox

I use Downthemall in firefox right now but it is not as reliable as it was on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not free but my favorite is [Speed Download](http://www.yazsoft.com/products/speed-download/). I went through a few free ones and ending up buying this on a [MUPromo](http://www.mupromo.com) special and it was worth every cent.

It supports resume, password protected sites, and can even FTP if you need it too. It also allows you to share files with other users on the network.

I have to admit, though, since moving to the Mac, my failure rates on downloads without a manager has drastically dropped if you're on a decent internet connection.

Comment: it's website says it has browser integration, so it seems  like good enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

## [iGetter](http://www.igetter.net/iGetter.html)

> iGetter is a full featured download manager and accelerator. With iGetter you can get the most out of your Internet connection (dial-up, wireless, cable, DSL, T1 etc.).
>
> iGetter can greatly improve the speed of your downloads using segmented (accelerated) downloading. In addition it allows auto resume on broken downloads, queue filtering by various criteria, scheduling downloads for low traffic periods, auto redial on broken connection, auto hang-up and shut down on completion, and much more.

## [Leech](http://manytricks.com/leech/)

Every modern browser has its own download functionality, so why should you use a separate application for handling downloads in the first place? Because Leech works better than any built-in download manager.

- Works with Browsers
- Downloads multiple files with ranges
- Works with listed downloads
- Works with listed downloads

Comment: I tried it and canned it. It crashed more then anything and it has a really clunky interface.

Comment: @Diago I never use a download manager, but I saw these.

Comment: I was more specifically looking for user feedback, these answer look like somebody copy pasted description from website.

Comment: @VaibhavMishra Hehe! That's because it was. :-)